# Can I set for example array[n+k] = array[0]?

Tags: c++, arrays

If I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    cin >> n;
    float array10[n];
    cin >> array10[i];
}
```

How can I create `array10[n+1]` and set the value of `array10[0]`?

Answer (score 6):

You can't. In fact, `array10[n];` isn't legal C++ (even if `n` was initialized). Variable length arrays aren't a C++ feature.

Use `std::vector`:

```
cin >> n;
std::vector<int> vec(n);
cin >> vec[i];
```

Comment: Interesting that it's not in the language. It compiles just fine in clang.

Comment: @Kevin compiler extensions.

Comment: He could instead do a dynamic allocation using `new`.

Comment: @Mauren why would he do that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859298/can-i-set-for-example-arraynk-array0/21859354?noredirect=1#comment33092744_21859615

Comment: Because he apparently wants to allocate the array based on some user input. Just wondering.

Comment: @Mauren so why not use std::vector?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore he may use any of them. I would use a regular array if I didn't need the array to extend on demand. As I said, I was just wondering whether his case was not this one. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
int n, i;
float array10[n];
```

is invalid because arrays in C+ require that their sizes would be constant expressions at compile time. (Though some compilers have its own language extensions that allow to do that. But this code does not satisfy the C++ Standard) And if an array is defined you may not change its size. 
If n would be a constant expression then you could write for example

```
const int n = 10;
float array[n];
float array1[n + 1]
```

Otherwise you have two approaches. Either you should use standard C++ container std::vector

For example

```
int n = 10;
std::vector<float> v( n );
```

and then you can resize this vector

```
v.resize( n + 1 );
```

Or you should dynamically allocate an array. For example

```
int n = 10;
float *array = new float[n];
```

and then reallocate it;

```
float *tmp = new float[n + 1];

std::copy( array, array + n, tmp );
delete []array;
array = tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by declaring array10 as a pointer

```
cin >> n;
float* array10 = new float[n];
cin >> array10[i];
//do something
delete[] array10;
```

Comment: And remembering to delete it later?

Comment: That's ub. Did you mean `delete[]`? Hint - this is why you prefer std::vector.